# Rails - How do I use application.html.erb in my custom layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a Controller called "Pages" with around 5 pages (views) for which I have rendered a layout called "page.html.erb". 
So my "Pages" Controller has:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
layout 'page'
```

I want my "page.html.erb" layout to use "application.html.erb" by default. How do I do make my custom layout "page.html.erb" to automatically have "application.html.erb" inherited/rendered in it?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't specify a layout in your controller, Rails will render your `application` layout by default.  If you follow this convention, you can use `application.html.erb` for your overall site page structure (also a good place to include stylesheets and javascript).  You can then use `= yield` in your layout to specify where your controller views should be rendered.

Controller actions by default will render their corresponding views.  For example, if you have an action `foo` in controller `bars_controller.rb`, Rails will render `/app/views/bars/foo.html.erb` unless you redirect or specify a different view to render in the action.  In fact, if all you want to do in action `foo` is render the page, you don't even need to define the action in your controller!

Convention over configuration my friend.

Comment: application.html.erb is taken by default. I have rendered a separate layout called 'Pages' which has only a Menu bar. All the other background and Header details are in my 'application' layout. I want to find a way to merge both 'application' and 'page' layouts. I guess that is not possible.

Comment: True you need to start with a base layout (or no layout) for each controller action and view.  For your case, I would recommend rendering page layout within the application layout conditionally.  So where ever you want the pages layout to appear: `<%= render 'layouts/pages' if params[:controller] == 'pages' %>`.  This will only include the pages layout within the application layout for the Pages controller.

Comment: Yes I implemented a similar method. Apart from my 'application' layout, I rendered the rest of the page data as a partial, and it gets displayed just fine.

Answer (score 3):

I usually split my layout into smaller partials (header, footer, HTML HEAD, etc). This way I can use multiple layouts by mixing different partials together.

Comment: It appears we won't be able to combine 2 layouts together. The best way as you told would be to render different partials. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge like you, but for mine I wanted my **home page** to have a slightly different **header** from the **other pages**.

**Here's how I got it working**:

All I had to do was to create 2 header partials in the `app/views/shared` directory:

```
_home_header.html.erb
_other_header.html.erb
```

Then I referenced it this way in the `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file:

```
<%= render partial: '/shared/home_header' if params[:controller] == 'homes' %>
<%= render partial: '/shared/other_header' if params[:controller] != 'homes' %>
```

It can also be referenced this way using an explicit if conditional:

```
<% if params[:controller] == 'homes' %>
  <%= render partial: '/shared/home_header' %>
<% elsif params[:controller] != 'homes' %>
  <%= render partial: '/shared/other_header' %>
<% else %>
<% end %>
```

Thank you [steve klein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3311657/steve-klein) for your comment that gave me an insight into this.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**